# SQL throwing ANSI_PADDING error even though it appears to be set correctly

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have a database project in VS which has several post-deployment scripts to fill the DB with data when it's published.

When I go to publish, SQL generates a master script from all the parts and pieces and builds the DB successfully, but when it hits the very first `INSERT` it throws this error

> : `INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.`

Upon examining the offending line of the script I found this immediately before the insert: `SET ANSI_PADDING ON`

Not only that, but at the very beginning of the auto-generated part of the script it has this: `SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` which appears to persist throughout the entire script.

Why is it giving me a hard time about the ANSI_PADDING when it's clearly set correctly?

**Edit:** I've tried setting the ANSI_PADDING explicitly ON and OFF with the same results. What's missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Off ANSI_PADDING and try to publish you Db project, below is code to off ANSI_PADDING

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

Comment: I get the same error whether it's explicitly set to OFF or ON